# Programmatically add content on UIWebView cursor position

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton, uiwebviewdelegate

I am loading HTML content in UIWebView. My page contains UIButton and UIWebView containing some HTML content. UIWebView is editable, so user can move to particular content of UIWebView.

What I actually want to do so, on button click text(suppose XYZ) should be added at that particular position in UIWebView.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Comment: I had already used that to load my static html. But I want to add text on UIButton click at user's cursor position in UIWebView.

Comment: to load html , you use, loadHTMLString method not stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method. First write some method in javascript which writes some text at cursor position and now call that method from Objective C using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will give you an idea to create a system like that, not tested.

```
NSString *stringData = @"this is test content"; 
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction(%@)", stringData]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using tinyMCE editor. So I had added below code on UIButton click, which solved my problem.

```
   NSString *strhtml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '%@');",@"Good Morning"];
  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strhtml];
```